# iOS sqlite3 encryption/decryption performance

Tags: ios, performance, memory-management, sqlite

We are trying to replace our own AES implementation to use the standard iOS AES implementation (see [Will our app be FIPS 140-2 compliant if we use our own AES algorithm implementation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9899/will-our-app-be-fips-140-2-compliant-if-we-use-our-own-aes-algorithm-implementat)). The original AES implementation encrypts and decrypts on source data buffer, thus no new allocation/free. With standard iOS AES implementation, we would have to malloc the memory for destination data buffer dynamically to encrypt/decrypt data. I am worried that frequent memory allocation and free could result in memory fragmentation. Current the memory allocation size would be 1K to 8K bytes (depending on iOS disk sector size, would be fixed on one particular device), so it should always be times of 1K.  However this allocation/free would be mixed up with memory allocation of other size, I am worried that this could create a lot of memory fragmentation.

One way we could solve this is to use a local variable with a fixed size (really the sqlite3 page size). The only problem is that page size could be range from 1K to 8K (depending on the iOS disk sector size, not sure if iOS device could reach 8K though) on different devices, so it would mean that I would have to allocate a 8K local buffer every time since I need to assign this size at compile time. Or I could always only allocate a smaller local buffer such as 2K to handle majority cases (at my iPhone, it is 1K), if data buffer is bigger than 2K, I would use dynamic allocation. It seems not ideal as well.

Should I worry about this here?  Maybe other standard encrypted sqlite3 implementation is already doing frequent memory allocation/free, so we are not much worse here? If you know any insight, please shed some lights here. It is really appreciated.

Comment: I'm not really answering your specific question... but I wouldn't worry optimizing for performance in advance.  Why not try it out, measure the performance and then see if it's worth optimizing.  The hardware AES implementation is probably going to be so much faster than your software implementation that any memory fragmentation or other performance concerns you have are going to be minor in comparison to the big gains you see.

Comment: @NicholasHart, thanks. So far we haven't seen any obvious slow down yet although we haven't do any performance profiling